# How do I upload a file from my iPad app to PHP to MYSQL?

Tags: php, mysql, ipad, upload, nsdata

I have found quite a bit of advice on the matter on the internet but nothing I try seems to work.  This is my objective-c code, based on the tutorial here: http://iphone.zcentric.com/2008/08/29/post-a-uiimage-to-the-web/

```
NSString *importFilePath = [openedUrl path];
NSString *filename = [importFilePath lastPathComponent];

//I changed this from initwithcontentsoffile because the program gets handed a url
//so I thought it made the most sense  
NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:openedUrl];


NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mysite.php?secret=%@&secret2=%@"]];
NSLog(@"the url: %@", [lastView uploadData:openedUrl]);
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSString *boundary = [NSString stringWithString:@"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449"];
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\";filename=\"%@\"\r\n",filename] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:data]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
// setting the body of the post to the reqeust
[request setHTTPBody:body];

// now lets make the connection to the web
NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

I changed the filename to the the new file's filename and the url to be my own.  Other than that, its pretty similar to the tutorial.

I have changed my php file.  When I hardcode in a url as the file, it works great.  However, when I try to pass it a file from my app, only the name gets passed, with no file contents. I am not sure if the part that is not working is from my php file or from my objective-c code.  Here is the new and improved php file:

```
<?
$username=$_GET['secret'];
$password=$_GET['secret2'];
$database="somedb";

mysql_connect(localhost,$username,$password);
@mysql_select_db($database) or die("Unable to select database");

$fileName = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
$tmpName  = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];

$testpage = file_get_contents('$tmpName');
$testpage = mysql_real_escape_string($testpage);
mysql_query("INSERT INTO tbldocuments(Description,Document) VALUES('$fileName','$testpage')");
mysql_close;   
?>
```

If you can see anything wrong with either snippet of code, please let me know - or if there is a gap in the way they interact or have any suggestions.

Thanks!
R

Comment: Is this the actual code? You initialize a `Filename` but dereference a `filename` variable in your Objective-C.

Comment: This PHP example must be from a 'bad' site or one dealing with outdated PHP versions. addslashes is a major deprecated method for preparing data for sql statement usage.

Comment: For the most part (the Filename part), this the actual code... I understand a lot of objective-c but I have to admit, I do not understand a lot of what is going on here - I thought I was putting the relevant filename in the FILE instead of the ipod.png that was in the example.  And the PHP is from this site: http://www.php-mysql-tutorial.com/wikis/mysql-tutorials/uploading-files-to-mysql-database.aspx  Should I ditch it and start again with the PHP? or work with this?

Comment: also, @sarnold, the real code did have lowercase f-> filename in both places.  Great catch though and thanks, I have edited it now.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this wrapper can solve most of your problems on the objective-c side of things.

http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use